# bitset<4> converted to wrong value on Win7 Embedded

Tags: c++, stringstream, bitset

I have the following piece of code to convert from Sixbit ASCII to an ASCII string:

```
    std::string SixBitToASCII(char *buffer)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        std::stringstream out;

        for (int index = 0; index < 16; index++)
        {
            std::bitset<4> bset(buffer[index]);

            std::cout << buffer[index] << " - " << bset << std::endl;

            ss << bset;
        }

        std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

        for (int index = 0; index < 60; index += 6)
        {
            std::string s = ss.str().substr(index, index + 6);
            std::bitset<6> bits;
            std::istringstream is(s);
            is >> bits;

            int asciiCode = bits.to_ulong() + 32;

            out << (char) asciiCode;
        }

        return out.str();
    }
```

It compiles fine. I´m compiling in a VS2012 Win7 Professional 32bits.

When I run it into an embedded Win7 I´m getting the following output:

```
8 - 1000
f - 0110 <<< ??? PROBLEM HERE
2 - 0010
9 - 1001 
2 - 0010
3 - 0011
4 - 0100
1 - 0001
0 - 0000
4 - 0100
1 - 0001
3 - 0011

100001100010100100100011010000010000010000010011
```

What is going on where is maked as a problem ? Converting `F` to `0100` ??? Isn´t is supposed to be `1111` ?

Of course the final conversion is wrong due to this error convering `F`. I´ve tried `std::bitset<4> bset((unsigned char) buffer[index])` with same results.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Converting F to 0100" ? Did you mean "Converting f to 0110" ? Which is correct for ASCII as Pete points out.  The ASCII code for `f` is 01100110 .  Maybe you're mixing up with the hexadecimal digit F.

Comment: It would help your question if you showed what was in `buffer` and also showed what you expected and which sixbit encoding you were using. The samples on Wikipedia don't include any lower-case letters amongst the 64 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see better what's going on, change

```
std::cout << buffer[index] << " - " << bset << std::endl;
```

to

```
std::cout << +buffer[index] << " - " << bset << std::endl;
```

That will show you the numeric value of `buffer[index]` instead of whatever character that numeric value represents. I don't now what "Sixbit ASCII" refers to, but with straight ASCII the result you're seeing is exactly what I'd expect: the ASCII code for the letter f is 0x66, so the low 4 bits are, indeed, 0110. You need to convert those character codes to digits. Again for ASCII (and for all standard character codes), values in the range `'0'` through `'9'` can be converted by subtracting `'0'`; values in the range `'a'` through `'f'` and `'A'` through `'F'` will require a more sophisticated lookup.

Comment: [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-bit_character_code for SixBit. The characters are 1byte hex values. BTW: What does the `+` do.. Now I see all decimal values (in this case 102 for f)... humm. I need to convert the text hex value to numeric hex value...

Comment: @Mendes - that Wikipedia article lists a bunch of variants. Regardless, that stream inserter shows the character value that each entry represents; to figure out what's going on, you have to look at the numeric value.

Comment: Pete, that helped me. I need a ASCII Literal to integer converter... Issue for a new topic... Thanks.